# Are Feynman rules unique?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

I am new here and I got a question that I never read in any textbook. Are Feynman rules actually unique or can one derive different rules, which are equivalent?

Of course, we have a freedom to choose a gauge. So my question concerns whether or not Feynman rules are unique after we have chosen such a gauge and if there is still the possibility to gain another Feynman rule, which is equivalent to the other one.

Comment: There is some freedom you have certainly, since for example you can use different choices of gauge in QED which result in a different expression for the propagator but give the same physical answers.

Comment: Okay, of course there is a gauge freedom we have. I forgot to mention that I am aware of this. But how is it besides the gauge that we can choose? After we have chosen a gauge, are the derived Feynman rules unique then?

Comment: Can you try to clarify the question?

Comment: Sure. :)

After we derived a particular Feynman rule and have chosen a particular gauge: is that derived Feynman rule then unique or is it possible, that still another equivalent Feynman rule can be derived?

I hope, I could clarify my question.
(Maybe I also should edit my original post to prevent confusion.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. There is no need to put the "edit" word when you edit. The question should be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways to rewrite Feynman rules! Here are just a few.

- As has already been pointed out, different gauges have different Feynman rules.
- The vertices depend on how you split the Lagrangian into free and interacting parts. For example, the propagator for a massive scalar field is usually $1/(p^2 + m^2)$, but one could also say the free part is the kinetic term alone, giving a propagator $1/p^2$. Then we gain a two point self-interaction from the mass term, which gives a factor of $m^2$. This point of view is useful when the Higgs mechanism is involved, because every 'free' particle really is massless.
- Similarly, the allowed vertices depend on the basis we choose for our propagating particles. For example, quarks/neutrinos in the mass basis can change generations upon interacting with a $W$ boson, but can't in the flavor basis. Which you use is up to convention and context.
- "Integrating out" some fields will give new Feynman rules from the effective interactions generated. For example, for scales much lower than the $W$-boson mass we can ignore the $W$ boson, at the cost of having a new, effective [four-fermion interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction).
- Feynman rules depend on how we group fields together; for example, a Dirac field is usually drawn as a plain line even though it contains four independent fields. You could alternatively have different lines for the Weyl spinors inside the Dirac field, as done [here](https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2012/03/19/dissecting-the-penguin/), and regard the Dirac mass as an interaction that swaps them. This is really the same as the third point, switching from the mass basis to the chirality basis.
- The adjoint representation for gluons is "almost" the same as the fundamental times and antifundamental, as 
  $$N \times \bar{N} = (N^2 - 1) + 1.$$
  Therefore we can write Feynman rules for gluons as if they're made of a fictitious charged particle and antiparticle pair, even though the Lagrangian says no such thing. This is called [t'Hooft double line notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298291/double-line-notation-three-and-four-gluon-vertices-how-is-this-a-simplificat) and is especially useful for large $N$.

Comment: I see, there are many different ways to construct the Feynman rules. And I was not aware of such a variety.
So, many ways exist and all of them can make the Feynman rule look different, right? Let say, after we have chosen a particular way, the Feynman rule is unique in that sense?

If yes, then I think my Question is solved. Thank you very much by now! :)

Comment: @Laboon Yup, there are a huge variety of ways to use Feynman rules. That reflects the fact that Feynman diagrams are tools for physicists, not ground truth, and we can use a tool however we want.